# How can I pass an object in params when using $router.push()?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to loop through an array of objects and when I click on an item I want to display a page populated with data from the other component.

Here is my router.js

```
{
    path: '/artists',
    component: () => import('../views/Artists/ArtistsStart.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: () => import('../views/Artists/Artists.vue')
      },
      {
        path: ':name',
        component: () => import('../views/Artists/Artist.vue')
      }
    ]
  }
```

`ArtistsStart.vue` only has `<router-view>` and a transition animation so I don't think it's important

`Artists.vue`

```
<template>
    <div v-for="(artist, index) in artists" :key="index" @click="artistLink(artist)">
        {{artist.name}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                artists: [{
                        name: 'artist 1',
                        route: 'artist1',
                        text: 'lorem ipsum',
                        imageUrl: ''
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'artist 2',
                        route: 'artist2',
                        text: 'lorem ipsum',
                        imageUrl: ''
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            artistLink(artist) {
                this.$router.push(`/artists/${artist.route}`);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I didn't use `<router-link>` because I don't want to pass the text and other data through the URL

`Artist.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            {{name}}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{text}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
            name: this.$route.params.name,
            text: this.$route.params.text
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I can only display the artist name in the `Artist.vue` page.

Comment: A single-file component cannot have 2 root elements. wrap both of those divs in a div, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`router.push` and `router-link` are meant to do the same thing which is to redirect you to a new location/address, for example, `/artists/1` (they are just doing it in a different way, dynamically vs statically). So in principle, it is the responsibility of that component to find the related data for this address, not the requester. In your case, it is the responsibility of the `Artist.vue` to find the data with the given artist Id, or artist route. In reality, you should have some method in this component to either fetch data from a local data store, e.g. using a vuex store or just plain js (put the `artist` list into a `artist.js` and reuse that in both `Artists.vue`, `Artist.vue`), or from a server using ajax.

Comment: I thought about using vuex but I haven't used it before so I was hoping I could manage to solve this only using vue router. This has to be the solution, thanks!